# How do I join three tables to get all data in one go?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got matches, teams and players (beach volleyball). One match consists of two teams (teamA and teamB). One team consists of two players (playerA and playerB).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (
    uuid        uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    created_at  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    user_id     integer REFERENCES users,
    first_name  text,
    last_name   text
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (
    uuid            uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    created_at      timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    user_id         integer REFERENCES users,
    player_1_uuid   uuid REFERENCES players,
    player_2_uuid   uuid REFERENCES players
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    uuid        uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    created_at  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    user_id     integer REFERENCES users,
    name        text,
    team_a_uuid uuid REFERENCES teams,
    team_b_uuid uuid REFERENCES teams
)
```

Now I'd like to get all match data with a single request for a given `user_id`. So far I've tried

```
    SELECT
        matches.uuid, matches.created_at, matches.name,
        teams.uuid, teams.created_at,
        players.uuid, players.created_at, players.first_name, players.last_name
    FROM matches
    LEFT JOIN teams ON matches.team_a_uuid = teams.uuid
    LEFT JOIN teams ON matches.team_b_uuid = teams.uuid
    LEFT JOIN players ON teams.player_1_uuid = players.uuid
    LEFT JOIN players ON teams.player_2_uuid = players.uuid
    WHERE user_id = $1
```

That does not give me all the four players (two players per team and two teams per match).

Any hints?

Comment: That query should raise an error. You need different table aliases when you include the same table more than once. And qualify the columns!

Comment: Can you give an data example what result of sql request that are you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this result you are looking for

```
SELECT matches.* , 
  team_a.* ,  team_a_player_1.* , team_a_player_2.* , 
  team_b.* ,  team_b_player_1.* , team_b_player_2.*  
FROM matches    
    LEFT JOIN teams as team_a ON matches.team_a_uuid = team_a.uuid
    LEFT JOIN players as team_a_player_1 ON team_a_player_1.uuid = team_a.player_1_uuid
    LEFT JOIN players as team_a_player_2 ON team_a_player_2.uuid = team_a.player_2_uuid
    LEFT JOIN teams as team_b ON matches.team_b_uuid = team_b.uuid
    LEFT JOIN players as team_b_player_1 ON team_b_player_1.uuid = team_b.player_1_uuid
    LEFT JOIN players as team_b_player_2 ON team_b_player_2.uuid = team_b.player_2_uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to only join each table once, but generalize your condition so either of the IDs can be matches:

```
SELECT
    matches.uuid, matches.created_at, matches.name,
    teams.uuid, teams.created_at,
    players.uuid, players.created_at, players.first_name, players.last_name
FROM matches
LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.uuid IN (matches.team_a_uuid, matches.team_b_uuid)
LEFT JOIN players ON players.uuid IN (teams.player_1_uuid, teams.player_2_uuid)
WHERE user_id = $1
```